# loop match() function over rows in r

Tags: r, loops, match

I need some help please:

my data

```
      c1   c2   c3   c4   c5   c6   c7   c8   c9  c10  c11  c12

1     33   43   63   23   34   32   31   41   61   21      <NA>
2     24   23   22   21   31   61   41      <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3     61   62   63   64   31   32   33   34   41   42   43   44
```

has 200 observations.

I now want to apply the match function (here just for row 1):

```
  > match(positions, RCA12[1,])
 [1] NA 10  7  8 NA  9 NA NA  6 NA NA NA NA  4  1  2 NA  3 NA NA  5 NA NA
[24] NA
```

over all 200 rows.

Is there a trick to do that ?
I tried the apply family but had no success.

Positions looks like this:

```
> positions
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "11" "12" "13" "14"
[2,] "21" "22" "23" "24"
[3,] "31" "32" "33" "34"
[4,] "41" "42" "43" "44"
[5,] "51" "52" "53" "54"
[6,] "61" "62" "63" "64"
```

My desired output then looks like this (for each observation, so 6 rows per observation, then next observation):

```
> matrix(match(positions, RCA12[1,]), ncol = 4)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   10   NA    4   NA
[3,]    7    6    1    5
[4,]    8   NA    2   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[6,]    9   NA    3   NA
```

Thanks in advance!
SB

Comment: awesome! thank you so much, that does the trick!.
my matrix then is:
finally <- matrix(apply(RCA12, 1, function(x) match(positions, x)), ncol = 4)

Comment: Cool. I'll change it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for `apply`.

```
apply(RCA12, 1, function(x) match(positions, x))
```